# Moving AVG over variable number of rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

In Snowflake, I would like to calculate a moving average for my data, but the number of rows in the average can change. Specifically, I want to factor into the average any records whose date is 30 days or less prior to the date in the current row. But there could be multiple records for each date, or missing dates.

For example:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | 100 |
| Jan 5 | 200 |
| Jan 20 | 100 |
| Feb 3 | 0 |
| Feb 3 | 500 |
| Feb 10 | 400 |
| Mar 8 | 600 |

I want the output to be:

| Date | 30d Avg | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | 100 | (calculated as `AVG(100)`) |
| Jan 5 | 150 | (calculated as `AVG(100, 200)`) |
| Jan 20 | 133 | (calculated as `AVG(100, 200, 100)`) |
| Feb 3 | 200 | (calculated as `AVG(200, 100, 0, 500)`) |
| Feb 10 | 250 | (calculated as `AVG(100, 0, 500, 400)`) |
| Mar 8 | 500 | (calculated as `AVG(400, 600)`) |

Using window frames doesn't seem to work here, because the number of inputs to the frame can change each time (depending on how many rows are less than 30 days before this one).

How can I do this?

Comment: Something like _RANGE BETWEEN  INTERVAL '30' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW_ perhaps - if supported.

Comment: I suggest you use a cte to tally your 0 - many rows into a single row for each day, and then use that computed cte with the snowflake preceding clause and lookback 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most databases, this can be done by using the window function `AVG` with window frame `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT Date, MAX(average) AS '30d_avg'
FROM (
  SELECT Date, AVG(Value) over(ORDER BY Date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as average
  FROM mytable
) AS s
GROUP BY Date
```

Since Snowflake does not support`RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL` this is a workaround :

```
SELECT 
   t1.Date,
   AVG(t2.Value) AS 30d_avg
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t2.Date >=  DATEADD(DAY, -30, t1.Date)  
                         AND t2.Date <= t1.Date
GROUP BY t1.Date
ORDER BY t1.Date
```

Demo tested on mysql : https://dbfiddle.uk/miO-qNsf

Comment: RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL isn't supported by Snowflake. Guess I'd need to replace it with a correlated subquery.

Comment: That is correct, I have edited my answer can you have a look

Answer (score -1):

-- snowflake has its 'way' of doing intervals like -> rows between 9 preceding and current row
--for example, from a QLIK Compose database you can
select d2.VIEWNAME , d2.ETL_RUNNO, d2.START_TIME
,AVG(d2.nbr_affected)
OVER ( partition by d2.viewname order by d2.START_TIME
rows between 9 preceding and current row  ) as "10_day_avg_num"